# style.css changes not being commited

Tags: html, css, xhtml

i'm working on an existing code in xhtml. I modified the background color in style.css, but the changes don t appear.

Here is my home.xhtml:

```
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
    <title><ui:insert name="title">Hello</ui:insert></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</h:head>
```

and in style.css in body part a changed the background color.. all i've done.. but still the old color appears. anyone have an idea?

thanks

Comment: Is there another place where the background-color is defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS files are usually saved in your browser's cache. Try reloading with `Shift+F5` or `Ctrl+Shift+R` instead of the regular `F5` / `Ctrl+R`

Note: The shortcut may depend on your browser.

Answer (score 1):

A trick I use every now and then to force the browser to not use a cached version of...anything is to add a variable to the end of the URL. The number and variable do not do anything but the browser will think it is a new page and download a fresh copy. Just change the number each time you want a fresh copy.

E.G.

```
http://example.com/?cache=123213
```